# Searching all columns in a table and displaying only those columns where keywords are matched in elasticsearch

Tags: csv, elasticsearch

I have a csv file with 100 rows and 10 columns which I have indexed into Elastic Search. Now I want to search for few keywords in the entire data. How to display only those columns where those keywords are matching?

Comment: can you please share some sample index data and expected search result ?

Comment: say my table has 4 cols : name, age, gender and height in that order and if I search for "Male", I want only gender column to be shown since only that col will have the matching keyword. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no exact way to show only the column that matched your query. But you can use [highlighting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.12/highlighting.html), to highlight the matched terms.

Adding a working example with index data, mapping, search query a search result

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "age": {
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "gender": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "height": {
        "type": "integer"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index Data:**

```
{
  "name": "c",
  "gender": "female",
  "age": 21,
  "height": 160
}
{
  "name": "a",
  "gender": "male",
  "age": 20,
  "height": 150
}
{
  "name": "b",
  "gender": "male",
  "age": 30,
  "height": 100
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "male"
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "*": {
        "type": "plain",
        "fragment_size": 20,
        "pre_tags": "<span class='bold'>",
        "post_tags": "</span>",
        "number_of_fragments": 1
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
 "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "67582942",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.35667494,
        "_source": {
          "name": "a",
          "gender": "male",
          "age": 20,
          "height": 150
        },
        "highlight": {
          "gender": [
            "<span class='bold'>male</span>"     // note this
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "67582942",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 0.35667494,
        "_source": {
          "name": "b",
          "gender": "male",
          "age": 30,
          "height": 100
        },
        "highlight": {
          "gender": [
            "<span class='bold'>male</span>"          // note this
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @ESCoder, this will work for now.